# How can I load php in a div with button onclick events in Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to load a table dynamically in a div in a php page. I want to load the tables using buttons or links on the same page.

I tried this:

```
<button id="fcluns" type="button" onclick="loadpage(this.id)">FC LUNs</button>
<div id="Table"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function loadpage(clicked_id){
if (clicked_id =="fcluns"){
    $("Table").html('loadingImage.gif').load('getfcLuns.php?name=<?php $Host=$_GET['name']; echo $Host;?>');
}
}
</script>
```

i am generating the table from a php page getfcLuns.php where mysql queries are executed to get the details from database. And i am getting the $host in this php and passing it to the helper php to generate the table.

Any other efficient way is welcome. But I want to keep the page php based only.

Comment: You CANNOT process PHP on the client side with an `onClick` event...consider using Ajax

Comment: can someone share a code snippet for an ajax implementation for this scenario?

Comment: Take an hidden variable with the value as $_GET['name']; Pass this variable value also to function loadpage()  and pass it in the parameter...

Comment: @Mr.Alien I don't think that is what is happening here, rather the page in question is generated using PHP. On the client side the PHP code in question would not show and would be replaced with the contents of `$_GET['name']`.

Comment: @Mike I guess he wants to show table on click, and than fetch the data from the db onclick event

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function loadpage(clicked_id){
  if (clicked_id =="fcluns"){
  $("#Table").load("getfcLuns.php?name=<?php $Host=$_GET['name']; echo $Host; ?>");
 }
     }
     </script>

Worked. used ajax too...
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"; type="text/javascript"> </script>
<button id="fcluns" type="button" onclick="loadpage(this.id)">FC LUNs</button>
<div id="Table"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function loadpage(clicked_id){
 if (clicked_id =="fcluns"){
    $("Table").load("getfcLuns.php?name=<?php $Host=$_GET['name']; echo $Host; ?>");
}
 }
 </script>
```

This above script Worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("#Table").css({'background-image':'loadingImage.gif'}).load(
    'getfcLuns.php?name=<?php echo $_GET[name];?>',
    function() {
        $(this).css({'background-image':'none'});
    }
);
```

Read the Documentation http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Worked with this :<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

Comment: @Tirtha Pratim Bhattacharjee please add it into your answer part and make accept, it will helpful to the others